# Using Robolectric alongside Google Analytics in Android

Tags: google-analytics, robolectric

I'm just experimenting with Robolectric 1.1 against an Android application that is using [GoogleAnalytics 1.4.2](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/resources).

On each call to GoogleAnalyticsTracker trackPageView Robolectrics ShadowSQLiteDatabase class is throwing an exception

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: transaction already successfully
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.shadows.ShadowSQLiteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful(ShadowSQLiteDatabase.java:291)
    at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.setTransactionSuccessful(SQLiteDatabase.java)
    at com.google.android.apps.analytics.PersistentHitStore.putEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker.createEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.google.android.apps.analytics.GoogleAnalyticsTracker.trackPageView(Unknown Source)
    at uk.co.bmc.rad.util.Analytics.trackPageView(Analytics.java:78)
    at uk.co.bmc.rad.ui.FindCragActivity.onCreate(FindCragActivity.java:95)
    at uk.co.bmc.rad.roboelectric.activities.FindCragActivityTests.setUp(FindCragActivityTests.java:36)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:27)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at com.xtremelabs.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner$1.evaluate(RobolectricTestRunner.java:292)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

The application runs fine and if I comment out the calls to GoogleAnalyticsTracker then the tests run ok too.

Am I missing something in my setup or...

Comment: Incidentally I'm injecting an Analytics implementation so I know I can (and have) inject a non-functional implementation into my tests to get around the problem.